# Как удалить файлы в Linux?

Tags: android, linux

Как удалить в папке Linux файлы одного типа например jpg. как в этом случае использовать команду rm?

Answer (score 2):

```
rm *.jpg
```

Comment: А нафига -rf ?

Comment: @dzhioev особенно непонятно, зачем -r. Надо же в папке удалить, а не во всех подпапках тоже.

Comment: спасибо, не надо

Comment: спасибо, на android эмуляторе работает как из shell'а так и из runtime.exec("rm *.jpg")

Comment: А вот -f не помешает, т.к. 


    avp@avp-ubu1:~/src$ ll xaxa
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 avp avp 1819 Apr 28 22:39 xaxa
    avp@avp-ubu1:~/src$ chmod -w xaxa 
    avp@avp-ubu1:~/src$ rm xaxa
    rm: remove write-protected regular file `xaxa'? n
    avp@avp-ubu1:~/src$ rm -f xaxa
    avp@avp-ubu1:~/src$ ls xaxa
    ls: cannot access xaxa: No such file or directory
    avp@avp-ubu1:~/src$ 

Т.е. для файлов закрытых от записи, rm без -f переходит в интерактивный режим, если stdin это терминал.

Answer (score 2):

У утилиты find есть атрибут -delete, который сразу удаляет найденные файлы, а также куча других опций, по которым она их ищет.
man find или https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find