# Как отменить установку репозитотия deadsnakes на Linux Debian 10? При вводе в консоль sudo apt update выводит ошибку связанную с deadsnakes

Tags: linux, debian

```
~$ sudo apt update
Ign:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu lunar InRelease
Err:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu lunar Release              
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 80]
Hit:3 https://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease                          
Hit:4 https://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease
Hit:5 https://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease
Ign:6 https://storage.googleapis.com/cros-packages/109 bullseye InRelease
Hit:7 https://storage.googleapis.com/cros-packages/109 bullseye Release
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu lunar Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: `$ grep -rl deadsnakes /etc/atp/sources.list*`

Comment: [ближайший по смыслу дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/452607/178576)

Comment: не помогает, возможно это связано с тем что это репозиторий не для дебиан?

Comment: в смысле не помогает? строки удалили/закомментировали?

Comment: выводит ту самую ошибку после sudo apt update, а после вашей команды выводит grep: /etc/atp/sources.list*: No such file or directory

Comment: а, ну я опечатался. эта команда всего лишь выдаёт список файлов, где упоминается "deadsnakes". вот без опечатки: `$ grep -rl deadsnakes /etc/apt/sources.list*`. // и на будущее: не тащите в системе всякий левый мусор.

Comment: yuriybiba27@penguin:~$ grep -rl deadsnakes /etc/apt/sources.list* .//
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-lunar.list
./.bash_history
./.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/greenlet/greenlet.cpp
Вывело что-то новое, но ошибка остается

Comment: 1. точку зачем добавили в конец команды? 2. эта команда всего лишь вывела имя файла, в котором встречается строка "deadsnakes". `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-lunar.list`. вот его и редактируйте. хотя, судя по имени, в нём только про этот левый мусорник и будет речь, так что можете и не редактировать, а просто удалить.

Comment: так и как мне его удалить? я уже запутался

Comment: как удалить то? для этого нужна какая-то команда?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/214552/178576

Answer (score 0):

Строка с указание на репозиторий может находиться не в самом файле /etc/apt/sources.list, а еще в файлах папки /etc/apt/sources.list.d Поэтому выполните команду

```
$ grep -r deadsnakes /etc/apt/sources.list*
```

Чтобы найти их все.

Comment: etc/apt/sources.list.d/deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-lunar.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu lunar main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-lunar.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu lunar main

Comment: И что мне делать дальше?

Comment: Я просто не понимаю что в этом линуксе и как

Comment: Те строчки которые вывел grep указывают на файл и найденную строку, содержащую  deadsnakes через двоеточие. Вам нужно удалить эти строки или закомментировать (написать # в начале строки). В вашем случае их две, вторая уже закомментирована. В терминале sudo nano etc/apt/sources.list.d/deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-lunar.list, затем корректируете строчку deb ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu lunar main, затем закрываете комбинацией ctrl-O - Enter - ctrl-x.